# InvalidProtocolBufferException in spark app when using (hadoop) FileSystem

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

When deploying a java app using spark, I got a `com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException` when using some `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` functionality.

I found the solution in the apache mailing list, which I share here for visibility (it took me quite some time to find it)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found here:
http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/InvalidProtocolBufferException-Protocol-message-end-group-tag-did-not-match-expected-tag-td21777.html

Basically I tried to use the port 50070 that I found in `hdfs-site.xml`, and also tried the 'https' 50470, and the usual 9000 too. The correct port was found in the `fs.defaultFS` property of the `core-site.xml`.